# How to use Python lambda without else?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to change the value of `myCol` if a condition is true. If the condition is not true, nothing should happen (if I do `else None`, it writes None as value to myCol)

```
tmp_df = someDataframe.groupby('ID').myCol.apply(lambda x: 'a' if (x=='A').any() else *DO NOTHING, THE myCol VALUE HAS TO STAY SAME*)

tmp_df=tmp_df.to_frame()
```

Comment: GroupBy expects a value for column myCol, wither it needs to be 'a' or something!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to leave the value unchanged you can set the `else` value to the lambda argument `x`:

```
df.col.apply(lambda x: new_value if some_condition else x)
```

In your language:

```
tmp_df = someDataframe.groupby('ID').myCol.apply(lambda x: 'a' if (x=='A').any() else x)
```

Comment: this does an Attribute Error

Comment: Can you supply a small sample dataframe that replicates this error?  It's not causing an error in the test I used, but maybe I'm not understanding your use case.  Also, is this Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity there is probably a more efficient answer here. I use np.where to get your answer.

```
 import numpy as np
 df['conditional'] = np.where(
      (df['conditional'] == 'A'), # Condition
      'a', # Value if true
      df['conditional'] # Value if false
      # /\ this is equal to the original value so it has no effect
 )
```

Documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: While the other answers may yield the same result, this will be more efficient for a large dataset with simply if statements. It may not matter with fewer than 1,000 records, but when you are in the millions it will certainly make a difference.

Comment: I think this won't work because I use a groupBy either than one row

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

```
tmp_df = someDataframe.groupby('ID').myCol.apply(lambda x: 'a' if (x=='A').any() else x)
```

Comment: Attribute Error

Comment: what is the type of myCol values?

Comment: tmp_df = someDataframe.groupby('ID').myCol.apply(lambda x: 'a' if (x=='A').any() else str(x) ))

Comment: so I think you want to do something like: 
tmp_df = someDataframe.groupby('ID').myCol.apply(lambda x: x.replace('A','a'))

Comment: str(x) takes '[values of the other columns], dtype: object'